# JSP scriptlet is showed in browser

Tags: html, css, jsp, browser, scriptlet

I'm working on a site for an exam project, I'm trying to show a catalog of products dinamically.
Example: There are n products in the DB, I want to create n "catel" div element, and diplay 3 element for every row.
I don't have any error, but on page launching I see only a cell and the scriptlet code is visible, how can I resolve this?

```css
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

header {
 float:left;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-left:0px;
 margin-right:-2px;
 padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 min-height:80px;
 height: 12%;
 width: 101%;
 background: white;
 opacity: 0.80;
 top:0%;
 position: fixed;
 overflow:hidden;
}

body{
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat:  no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size:  cover;
 overflow:hidden;

}

table.head{
 width: 100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}

table.head tr{
 margin-left:0;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:0
}

table.head tr td.first{
   width:40%;
}

table.head tr td.second{
 width:60%;
}



div.logo{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 width:250px;
 height:75px;
 /*width: 32%;
 height: 20%;*/
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 margin-left:2%;
 
}

div.logocell{
 display:none;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 position:absolute;
 right:10px;
}

.imgcell{
 width:80px;
 height:80px;
 
}

table.head tr td.first div.logo a img.logo{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

div.topnav{
 overflow: hidden;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding-right:2.5%;
}

div.topnav a{
 border-radius: 25px;
 float: right;
    display: block;
    color: #180B30;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

div.topnav a:hover{
 background-color:#180B30;
 color:white;
}


/*smartphone*/
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  table.head tr td div.topnav {display: none;}
  table.head tr td.first div.logo{display:none;}
  table.head tr td.first div.logocell{display:inline;}
  table.head tr td.second div.container{display:none;}
  table.head tr td.first div.container#ico{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:7%;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
  }
 section div.dropdown-content {
  float:left;
  margin-left:0px;
  padding-left:0pc;
     display: none;
     position: fixed;
     left:0;
     top:80px;
     min-width:240px;
     min-height: 300px;
     width: 20%;
     height:100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     z-index: 1;
     background: white;
  opacity: 0.80;
  }
  div.container#frame{
    width:99%;
    height:79%;
    min-width:350px;
    left:0.5%;
    top:12.5;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
  footer div.social a.fa {
   font-size:300%;
   width:50%;
   margin-right:5%;
   margin-left:4%;
   padding-right:15%;
   text-align:center;
  }
  footer div.social{
  padding-right:15%;
  margin-left:5%;
  }
  section article#descrizione{
  margin-bottom:50%;
  }
  section article#colel{
  padding-bottom:25%;
  }
  section div#cont{
  margin:1% 1% 35% 1%;
  height:120%;
  width:98%;
  } 
  form#login h3{
  font-size:130%;
  }
  input[type=text], input[type=password]{
  width:70%;
  height:10%;
  }
  section form#login .button#entra{
  min-width:60px;
  width:10%;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  padding:0;
  }
  section form#login{
  margin-top:25%;
  }
  section div#login{
 float:top;
 width:96%;
 height:75%;
 border-radius: 25px;
 margin:6% 2% 2% 2%;
  }

  section div#signup{
 float:bottom;
 width:96%;
 height:125%;
 border-radius: 25px;
 margin:5% 2% 35% 2%;
  }
  
  section div#signup form#reg button#registrati{
  width:40%;
  }
  section div#general{
  margin-top:3%;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
  section div#signup form#signup{
  margin:2% 0 2% 0;
  width:96%;
  padding:0;
  }
  section div#signup form#reg .button#registrati{
  width:130px;
  }
}

/*tablet*/
@media screen and (min-width:401px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  table.head tr td div.topnav {display: none;}
  table.head tr td.first { width: 60%; height:12%;}
  table.head tr td.second { padding-right:2%;}
  table.head tr td.second div.container#ico{
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:4%;
    margin-right:2%;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
  }
  div.container#frame{
    width:100%;
    height:75%;
    top:16.5%;
    overflow:hidden;
    left:0%;
  }
  footer div.social{
    padding-right:50px;
    margin-left:5%;
  }
  footer div.social a.fa {
   font-size:300%;
   width:80px;
   margin-right:2%;
   padding-right:50px;
   text-align:center;
  }
  section article#descrizione{
  margin-bottom:30%;
  }
  section div#cont{
  margin:2% 2% 13% 2%;
  height:115%;
  max-height:650px;
  width:96%;
  }
  form#login h1{
  font-size:200%;
  }
  input[type=text], input[type=password]{
  width:70%;
  max-width:250px;
  height:10%;
  }
  section form#login .button#entra{
  min-width:60px;
  width:10%;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  padding:0;
  }
  section div#general img{
  min-height:400px;
  z-ondex:-1;
  }
  section div#general div#button{
  margin-top:100px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:0;
  }
  section div#signup{
  height:75%;
  margin-top:2%;
  margin-bottom:10%;
  overflow:auto;
  }
  section div#signup form#reg{
  width:90%;
  
  }
}
/*computer*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .dropdown-content{display:none;}
  .show{display:none;}
  .topnav.responsive .container#ico {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.container#ico{
 background-color: transparent;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    float: right;
    margin-top:4%;
    margin-bottom:4%;
    margin-right:4%;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 250%;/*35*/
    height: 15%;/*5*/
    background-color: #333;
    color: #180B30;
    margin: 30% 0%;
    transition: 0.4s;
    float: center;
    opacity:1;
    
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

.dropdown-content {
 float:right;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
    top:80px;
    min-width:240px;
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 20%;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
 opacity: 0.80;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: #180B30;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover{
 display:block;
 background-color:#180B30;
 color:white;
 opacity:0.70;
}

.show {
 display:block;
 overflow:hidden;
}

section{
 background-color:transparent;
 display:block;
 top:12%;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 margin:3px 0 0 0; 
 overflow:auto;
}

div#gallery{
 /*background-color:grey;*/
 width:100%;
 opacity:1;
 border:1px solid white;
 color:white;
 font-size:120%;
 position:relative;
 margin-top:5%;
 padding:0.5% 3%;
 margin-left:0;
 margin-right:0;
 margin-bottom:50%;
  
}

div#gallery div#catel{
 background-color: grey;
 opacity:0.9;
 border:1px solid white;
 padding:3% 5%;
 margin-bottom:5%;
 
}

div#gallery div#catel img{
 width: 100%; 
 height:300px;
 opacity:1;
}

div#gallery div#catel div#des{
 color:white;
 text-decoration: none;
}



footer{
 display:block;
 background: white;
 min-height:40px;
 max-height:40px;
 width:100%;
 bottom:0px;   
 position:fixed;  
 opacity: 0.9;
 overflow:hidden;
}

footer div.social{
 width:100%;
 height:80%;
 display:inline;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 opacity:0.9;
}

footer div.social a.fa {
    font-size: 200%;
    width: 3%;
    height:50%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position:relative;
    opacity:0.9;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.fa-facebook:hover {
 color:#3B5998;
 background:white;
}

.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color:white;
}

.fa-twitter:hover{
 background:white;
 color:#55ACEE;
}
.fa-google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}

.fa-google:hover{
 background:white;
 color:#dd4b39;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}

.fa-linkedin:hover{
 background:white;
 color:#007bb5;
}
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.ArrayList;" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>IROPLAS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\WebContent\WEB-INF\style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body
 background="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\img\background.jpg">
 <header class="container-fluid">
 <table class="head">
  <tr>
   <td class="first">
    <div class="container" id="ico" onclick="menuCross(this)">
     <div class="bar1"></div>
     <div class="bar2"></div>
     <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="logocell">
     <a href="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\WebContent\Home.html">
      <img class="imgcell"
      src="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\img\Logocell.png"
      alt="logo">
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
     <a href="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\WebContent\Home.html">
      <img class="logo"
      src="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\img\logo_2.jpg"
      alt="logo">
     </a>
    </div>

   </td>
   <td class="second">
    <div class="topnav" id="topNav">
     <a
      href="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\WebContent\Profilo.html">Profilo</a>
     <a
      href="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\WebContent\Contatti.html">Contatti</a>
     <a
      href="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\WebContent\Prodotti.hmtl">Prodotti</a>
     <a
      href="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\WebContent\Collaborazioni.html">Collaborazioni</a>
     <a
      href="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\WebContent\Azienda.html">Azienda</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="ico" onclick="menuCross(this)">
     <div class="bar1"></div>
     <div class="bar2"></div>
     <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </header>
 <section>
 <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropDown">
  <h2>
   <a
    href="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\WebContent\Azienda.html">Azienda</a>
   <a
    href="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\WebContent\Collaborazioni.html">Collaborazioni</a>
   <a
    href="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\WebContent\Prodotti.html">Prodotti</a>
   <a
    href="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\WebContent\Contatti.html">Contatti</a>
   <a
    href="C:\Users\bufal\workspace\ProgettoTSW\WebContent\Profilo.html">Profilo</a>
  </h2>
 </div>

 <!-- barra filtri + ricerca --> 
 <%! ArrayList<Model.BProdotto> a = Model.BProdottoDAO.doRetrieveAll();%>
 <%! int n = Model.BProdotto.getNumeroProdotti(a);%>

 <div id="gallery">
  <% do { %>
  <div class="row">
   <% do { %>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="catel">
     <img src="C:\\Users\\bufal\\Desktop\\2.jpg" alt="Lights">
     <div id="des">
      <h3 id="nome">NomeProdotto</h3>
      <p id="prezzo">Prezzo</p>
      <!-- carrello -->
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <% } while (n%3!=0); %>
   
  </div>
  <% } while (n>0); %>
 </div>

 </section>

 <script>
  function menuCross(x) {
   x.classList.toggle("change");
   document.getElementById("dropDown").classList.toggle("show");
  }

  function menuOff() {
   var x = document.getElementById("topNav");
   if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
   } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
   }
  }
 </script>
 <footer>
 <div class="social">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="social">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="social">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="social">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-google"></a>
 </div>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**Browser view**

[image]

Comment: Paste your code snippet instead of images.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As it currently stands your questions might be impossible to answer! Before you dump all your code, please simplify it. You might not get any help if you just dump 200 lines of code here. Please try to provide some minimal, reproducable code for your problem. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is just syntax problem. use any IDE to write code.

Comment: @SumeshTG I'm using Eclipse Java Neon